# Excel Scalable Recipe Ingredients

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this recipe that goes into making this coffee per cup. The standard cup size is 210 ans the recipe that goes is 190 ml water and 2 grams coffee. I want a formula that helps me adjust the ingredients automatically when i change the cup size to say: 330 or anything else.

[image: **View this link to know what I'm looking for**]

SO This is what ive come up with until now:
1. Calculating a conversion factor, for example dividing 330 by 210 and then multiplying it with the ingredients.

Can anyone tell me if this the way to go.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say your cup size is in cell `B1`,

For your coffee, which would be in Cell `C2`, you would use this formula:

```
=(B1/210)*2&" grams"
```

For your water, which would be in Cell `C3`, you would use this formula:

```
=(B1/210)*190&" ml"
```